# Camel Spring Boot Archetype builds project with missing artifact

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, maven-archetype

When I run the mvn command to create a Spring Boot Camel project using the Camel Spring Boot archetype the resulting pom.xml gives a dependency error.

`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-spring-boot -DarchetypeVersion=2.16.0 -DgroupId=test -DartifactId=app`

I get the error: 
`Missing artifact org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot:jar:2.16.0`

If I change the version to 2.15.0 the problem goes away.

Is there some kind of problem with version 2.16.0?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to delete my local Maven repository and rebuild.

Delete the artifacts (or the full local repo) from `c:\Users\username\.m2\repository` by hand.

Comment: It says I need to wait 18 hours before I can mark it as answered